Divide WebSocket server and HTTP (Express) server into two documents
I am making a backend which contains a websocket connection and a HTTP connection. For now, I have everything in one single document, which is messy and hard to read. I was wondering if there is any good way to "route" them into their own documents?
Essentially if I can have all definitions, hosting etc. in "main.ts", all websocket listeners in "ws.ts" and all HTTP endpoints in "http.ts".
Thanks in advance!
For now, I have this main.ts for making the server dual between HTTP and WS:
import http, {
    Server as HTTPServer,
    IncomingMessage as HTTPRequest
} from "node:http";

import {
    WebSocketServer as WSServer,
    WebSocket as WS
} from "ws";

import express, {
    Express as ExpressServer,
    Request as ExpressRequest,
    Response as ExpressResponse,
    NextFunction as ExpressNext
} from "express";

const es: ExpressServer = express();
const server: HTTPServer = http.createServer(es);
const wss: WSServer = new WSServer({server});

